# Python/Cherrypy: set cookie on redirect

Tags: python, redirect, cookies, cherrypy

I am trying to figure out how to set a cookie just before a redirect from Cherrypy. My situation is this:

- when a user logs in, I would like to set a cookie with the users username for use in
  client-side code *(specifically, inserting the users name into each
  page to show who is currently logged in)*.

The way my login system works is that after a successful login, the user is redirected to whatever page they were trying to access before logging in, or the default page. Technically they are redirected to a different domain, since the login page is secure while the rest of the site is not, but it is all on the same site/hostname. Redirection is accomplished by raising a `cherrypy.HTTPRedirect()`. I would like to set the cookie either just before or just after the redirect, but when I tried setting `cherrypy.response.cookie[<tag>]=<value>` before the redirect, it does nothing. At the moment I have resorted to setting the cookie in every index page of my site, in the hopes that that will cover *most* of the redirect options, but I don't like this solution. Is there a better option, and if so what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: It would appear that if I add `cherrypy.response.cookie[<tag>]['path'] = '/'` after setting the cookie value, it works as desired.